# Python SSH / SFTP Module?

Tags: python, ssh, sftp

I've been looking around for a module which allows me to do SSH / SFTP functions in python without using POPEN to do it manually. Is there anything like this? I haven't found any real information on this, thanks!

Comment: paramiko? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+ssh+sftp

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're probably looking for the excellent paramiko library:

http://www.paramiko.org/

Answer (score 4):

paramiko works nicely: [Paramiko Homepage](http://www.paramiko.org/)

Answer (score 2):

For SFTP, you can use [pysftp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysftp), which is a thin wrapper over paramiko's SFTPClient (`pip install sftp`).

Example to download a file:

```
import pysftp #pip install sftp
import sys

hostname = "128.65.45.12"
username = "bob"       
password = "123456"  

sftp = pysftp.Connection(hostname, username=username, password=password)

sftp.get('/data/word_vectors/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.txt', preserve_mtime=True)
print('done')
```

Comment: I like the pysftp package, and I like that you noted that it's called `sftp` when installing via pip, despite being imported as `pysftp`. However, I needed a new installation recently (for Python 3.6), and pip actually wants `pysftp` now. In addition, for better security, you now have to explicitly disable host key checking if you want to use password-only authentication. This isn't hard to do at all (a couple extra lines of code, and the warning message and docs spell out what you need to do), but you might want to update your answer to reflect these changes.

Comment: @JohnY thanks good to know. I am not using the package at the moment; if you have some code snippet you're most welcome to update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're looking to do over ssh, you might also benefit from looking at the pexpect library: http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect